# capacity problem with some packages

Tags: pgfplots, memory, capacity

I 'm trying to draw the plot of **f(x)=sin(1/x)** with `pgfplot`, but I get an error message:

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].

I realized that when I delete one of the packages marked with `%!!!` in my code, everything is all right. [This](https://pastebin.com/DTM9Pzn4) is the `log`-file.

What is going wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}%!!!
\usepackage{mathtools}%!!!
\usepackage{subcaption}%!!!
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}%!!!
\usepackage{fancybox}%!!!
\usepackage{wasysym}%!!!    

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}   

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}%!!!
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}%!!!
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}%!!!
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,decorations.pathreplacing}%!!!
\usetikzlibrary{spy}%!!!
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit,arrows}%!!!

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.2,
    ymax=1.2,
    ticks=none,
    height=0.3\textwidth,
    width=0.6\textwidth,]
    \addplot[domain=0.01:1.5, thin,samples=5000] {sin(deg(1/(x)))};
    \addplot[domain=-1.5:-0.01, thin,samples=5000] {sin(deg(1/(x)))};
    \node at (axis cs:1.4,0.8) {$C_f$} ;
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: For me it works fine, with no errors. I could create the bi-directional chirp-like signal without any issues. My TeX distribution is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.6)  14 MAR 2019 11:55`. Please add your `TeX` distribution. Please see here: https://imgur.com/a/2PioUke

Comment: @Raaja thank's for your answer! My TeX distribution is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.2.10)  14 MAR 2019 11:30`

Comment: For me it also compiles using TeX Live 2018 frozen. Are you sure all packages are up to date? both as user and admin?

Comment: @daleif you are almost right about the updating. I just update miktex's packages (with `miktex console`, so there wasn't any option for admin or user) and the code is OK. **But**, when **1)** I change `0.6\textwidth` to `0.8\textwidth` or **2)** I use this code to the book that I write, I have the same problem...

Comment: MikTeX console can update as both user and admin, see https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console under "Operation Mode", you need to update both, as the user part (the default) only updates the packages you installed

Comment: It is a common problem that plots with too many points (or where too many things need to be calculated) can cause TeX to run out of memory. You could switch to LuaTeX, which has dynamic memory allocation and should not run out of memory that quickly (of course memory is still limited by your hardware), you could think about externalising the picture (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398753/35864, if it compiles in a smaller document at all) or just produce the graph with an external application. Of course you could also choose a smaller `samples` value: `5000` is a lot.

Comment: The document compiles for me, but it uses 2999187 words of memory. If your miktex has only 3000000 reserved that's quite near the exhaustion point. You should enlarge the memory.

Comment: @daleif , I can't find how to change "Operation Mode". At the place that is writing "Operation Mode" in `miktex console` is also writing "you have installed miktex for your private use".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I 'm sorry, but I have no idea how to enlarge the memory, and I didn't manage to understand from the sites that I visited. Have you got a link with a simple example?

Comment: @moewe **1)** Do you mean "LuaLaTeX"? I have problems for now for this switching. **2)** Smaller `samples` make the plot clearly not correct. **3)** I have no idea how to externalising the picture, and I didn't manage to understand from `pgfplot`-manual. Have you got a link with a simple example?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438911/2388. Exchange all occurences of xelatex by pdflatex.